# Crawled properties missing for Business Data source

Tags: 2010, bcs, fast-search

We've implemented and crawled a Business Data Connectivity Service data source. I can find the items based on the values in their fields, but when I look at Crawled Properties, there is only the default [EntityName(Text) and EntityNamespace(Text) properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134087(v=office.14).aspx) available. None of the fields of the items show up [as they should.](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/04/15/mapping-enterprise-search-managed-properties-from-the-bcs-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks to [this post](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/02/04/searching-database-content-with-fast-search-for-sharepoint-2010-part-3-using-the-bcs-aspx-2/).

> Now when you are in the **FAST Query Search Service Application, don’t
>   click on the Metadata properties link in the left menu**, ‘these
>   aren’t the search properties you’re looking for’ /waveshand.

I was looking at Crawled Properties under FASTQuerySSA, while I should have looked under Search Service Application.